# Was Qui Gon guiding Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker

In *Star Wars : The Attack of The Clones*, with interpreting this scene, can we say that Qui Gon was guiding Anakin all the time?

Note:  The scene is when Anakin kills the Tusken Raiders.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you'd like to spoiler tag the note.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - The film is 14 years old and has been seen by over three billion people. I think the spoiler ship has not only sailed, but safely docked on the other shore and the crew's gone off to get hammered in a local bar.

Comment: Isn't the stand of this site's policy that important plot points should be protected no matter how old or popular the show is, unless it is something as ubiquitously known in popular culture as Vader's quote? My suggestion here is on a best practice basis.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Our spoiler policy is both inconsistent and incoherent but the one thing we seem to agree on is that relatively minor plot points in films that are decades old are generally protected by tags and that spoiler blocks are largely unnecessary. If you're scared of learning *how* Vader turned evil, you shouldn't be looking at questions about Anakin under the "Attack of the Clones" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It was Yoda hearing Qui-Gon Jinn's reaction to what Anakin had just done.**

Qui-Gon Jinn just learned how to retain consciousness after death, although he was not able to physically manifest himself.

[Qui-Gon Jinn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn)

> Though his training had been incomplete, Jinn utilized what he learned
>   from the Force Priestesses to become one with the Force and retain his
>   identity after his death. He had not fully learned the mystery,
>   however, so he could not physically manifest himself, only speak as a
>   disembodied voice.

Then is further explained that the first time he was able to show his presence in some form was when Anakin slaughtered all the Tusken.

> The first known time that Jinn communicated through the Force was
>   shortly before the outbreak of the Clone Wars. Skywalker had returned
>   to Tatooine to find his mother, about whom he had been having
>   recurring nightmares, and discovered she had been kidnapped by Tusken
>   Raiders. He found her in a Tusken camp, but she died only moments
>   later. In his anger, Skywalker slaughtered all the Tuskens in the
>   camp. **Jinn, sensing the great pain and distress, called out to**
>   **Skywalker through the Force**, which Yoda could hear—but not
>   comprehend—through his own meditations

Then it is shown that Yoda was just learning to communicate with Qui-Gon , which happened to be when Yoda hears his reaction to the slaughter.

> Yoda was only just beginning to learn how to
>   communicate with him. **As he meditated, he was hearing Qui-Gon's**
>   **reaction to seeing Anakin killing the Sand People on the other side.**

So no, Qui-Gon Jinn was not guiding Anakin.